# SQL Server: Iterate over rows of one table, while comparing result sets from two other tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables that look something like this;

Students

```
studentID    studentName
1            John
2            Jack
3            Jane
```

Subjects

```
subjectID    subjectName
1            maths
2            geography
3            history
4            physics
```

Performance

```
studentID    subject_passed    mark_obtained
1            maths             40
2            physics           50
1            geography         40 
3            maths             80
1            physics           40
2            maths             70
2            geography         40
1            history           30
```

Using the above example, what I want to do is to select all students that passed all subjects AND have total marks exceeding 120.

This is what I have so far tried;

1. Using a CURSOR (and while loop) to iterate over the studentIDs, then use EXCEPT to find differences between the two result sets like this

```
[declarations]
[set CURSOR]
[FETCH NEXT]
while @@FETCH_STATUS
BEGIN
    SELECT subject FROM Subjects
        EXCEPT
    SELECT subject FROM Performance WHERE studentId=@id 
    [FETCH NEXT]
END
```

I am encountering two challenges with this approach; 
    It returns n(number of students) different result sets
    I also can't figure out how to incorporate the second condition about the SUM, considering aggregate functions are not allowed in the WHERE clause.

2. I also tried to select 'all subjects' into a list, and 'all subjects a student passed' into another list and compare them like this;
   `select student from Students where (select string_agg(all subjects)) = (select string_agg(subject passed by student))`
   but i still run into the same challenge of failing to incorporate the second condition of the SUM into the whole mix of things.

The requirement is to select students who passed all subjects and have total marks exceeding 120.
I appreciate any guidance on how to go about this.

Comment: What is the criteria to pass the subject? I mean the minimum mark to pass

Comment: That's a very well-executed question.  You provided sample data and showed what you've tried so far.  The only constructive criticism I have is that it would be nice to have the desired results spelled out, rather than just described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `CROSS JOIN` to get a list of every student and every subject, and then `LEFT JOIN` to the table `Performance`. Then you can use a `HAVING` clause to filter out those that passed all subjects, with a total mark more than 120. I filter out those that haven't passed everything with a conditional count, where I only count the rows where `mark_obtained` has the value `NULL` in the table `Performance` (which I assume would only happen if there is no row for the student/subject).

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Student (StudentID int, StudentName varchar(5));
INSERT INTO dbo.Student (StudentID,
                         StudentName)
VALUES(1,'John'),
      (2,'Jack'),
      (3,'Jane');

CREATE TABLE dbo.Subject (SubjectID int, SubjectName varchar(10));
INSERT INTO dbo.Subject (SubjectID,
                         SubjectName)
VALUES(1,'maths'),
      (2,'geography'),
      (3,'history'),
      (4,'physics');

CREATE TABLE dbo.Performance (StudentID int, subject_passed varchar(10), mark_obtained int);
INSERT INTO dbo.Performance (StudentID,
                             subject_passed,
                             mark_obtained)
VALUES (1,'maths',40),
       (2,'physics',50),
       (1,'geography',40),
       (3,'maths',80),
       (1,'physics',40),
       (2,'maths',70),
       (2,'geography',40),
       (1,'history',30);

GO

SELECT St.StudentID,
       St.StudentName,
       SUM(P.mark_obtained) AS Marks_obtained
FROM dbo.Student St
     CROSS JOIN dbo.Subject Su
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Performance P ON St.StudentID = P.StudentID
                                AND Su.SubjectName = P.subject_passed --This should really be ID
GROUP BY St.StudentID,
         St.StudentName
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN P.mark_obtained IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 0
   AND SUM(P.mark_obtained) > 120

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.Performance;
DROP TABLE dbo.Subject;
DROP TABLE dbo.Student;
```

This is a far better method than using a `CURSOR`. SQL Server excels are set based methods, not iterative ones, and a Cursor falls in the latter.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cc347fb15391b73aa133fe97063c4344)

Comment: Perfect! This does it - Couldn't have figured doing it this way. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using [CTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression), statistics per student could be gathered in a separate subquery:

```
WITH StatisticsPerStudent AS
(   SELECT studentId,
            COUNT(1) AS TotalSubjectsPassed,
            SUM(mark_obtained) AS TotalMarks
    FROM Performance
    GROUP BY studentId
) SELECT *
    FROM Students
        JOIN StatisticsPerStudent ON StatisticsPerStudent.studentId = Students.studentId
  WHERE 
        StatisticsPerStudent.TotalSubjectsPassed = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Subjects) --passed all subjects
        AND StatisticsPerStudent.TotalMarks > 120  --total marks exceeding 120
```

Comment: Aside: A CTE is not executed in discrete steps that create temporary tables, it is processed by the query optimizer which may generate a execution plan that merges all of the steps into a single query.

Comment: @HABO, thanks for comment, I've fixed my answer by removing mentioning temporary table

Comment: @Renat Thanks for this solution. The approach is good, easy to follow.